# Set tax for previous orders

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have set tax for a magento site and it is working fine. Now I want to **set the same tax calculation for the previous orders**. I have decided to change the values manually in database. Is there any other way to set tax for previous orders?
 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set tax for the orders which have already been made. If you will try to make the changes directly in the database then you will have to change it in all tables related to sales_flat which could break your store.

Comment: Is it possible to reorder those orders?

Comment: Yes, you can reorder those orders from admin area.. This would apply tax.

Comment: Thanks Abhinav. Those orders were in **complete** status